# Google Apps Scripts: How to keep track of selected dates with CardService.newDatePicker?

Tags: google-apps-script, add-on

Use selects a date from `CardService.newDatePicker`:

```
const DatePickerFrom = CardService.newDatePicker()
    .setTitle("From Day")
    .setFieldName("range_start")
    .setValueInMsSinceEpoch(todayDate.getTime())
    .setOnChangeAction(
      CardService
        .newAction()
        .setFunctionName("handleRangeStartChange")
    );
```

I need to remember what date they select to perform other actions later...

```
const scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();

scriptProperties.setProperties({
  "rangeStart": new Date(),
  "rangeEnd": new Date(),
  "dayStartHour": 9,
  "dayStartMinutes": 0,
  "dayEndHour": 17,
  "dayEndMinutes": 0,
  "busyBlocks": []
});

function handleRangeStartChange(e) {
  const rangeStart = formatDate(new Date(e.formInput.range_start.msSinceEpoch));
  scriptProperties.setProperty("rangeStart", rangeStart);
}
```

But later on, when I log the values from `scriptProperties`, the updated values are NOT there. It logs default same values from `setProperties`.

```
function logParams() {
  const params = scriptProperties.getProperties();
  Logger.log(params)
}
```

How is it possible to keep track of user selected values when building Google Add-Ons?

FYI, my Add-On is a Card Add-On for Calendar.

Comment: What is formatDate()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PropertiesService Saves everything as strings I believe so perhaps this would work:

I tried this simple example and it works okay:

```
function setProps() {
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty("mydate",new Date().valueOf().toFixed(0));
  Logger.log(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty("mydate"));
  Logger.log(new Date(Number(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty("mydate"))))
}

Execution log
4:47:45 PM  Notice  Execution started
4:47:45 PM  Info    1655851665625
4:47:45 PM  Info    Tue Jun 21 16:47:45 GMT-xxxx 2022
4:47:46 PM  Notice  Execution completed
```

So with your function:

```
function handleRangeStartChange(e) {
  const rangeStart = new Date(e.formInput.range_start.msSinceEpoch.toFixed(0));//not sure about this
  scriptProperties.setProperty("rangeStart", rangeStart);
}
```

I think you will want to do the same thing with setting script prooperties

```
scriptProperties.setProperties({
  "rangeStart": new Date().valueOf().toFixed(0),
  "rangeEnd": new Date().valueOf().toFixed(0),
  "dayStartHour": 9,
  "dayStartMinutes": 0,
  "dayEndHour": 17,
  "dayEndMinutes": 0,
  "busyBlocks": []
});
```